# Twitter bootstrap carousel navigation arrows out of the image

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I put in my bootrap carousel some 940x120 images, i want the navigation arrows of the carousel to be out of the image, so they don't cover it. If did this:

```
.carousel-navigation.left {  
    margin-left: -45px;
}

.carousel-navigation.right {
    margin-right: -45px;
}
```

When the Carousel cycles trough images the image bounce on the left side, like if it's following the arrow initial position for half second, then goes back to correct position, but this effect while cycling is not nice. How can i avoid this?

Here's my example: http://jsfiddle.net/WmMXa/3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that that bug was happening just when using LESS CSS (i was using nesting rules), if I do it in plain css the image do not bounce and work normally. Good to know.