# Get carousel control arrow out of the carousel frame

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have a directive that is basically an extension of carousel from Angular UI bootstrap.

However, I have been trying to get the carousel control arrow out of the frame by overriding the CSS (with my own), but no luck.
I have tried what is suggested in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15951120/twitter-bootstrap-carousel-navigation-arrows-out-of-the-image) but still no luck.

What I did as a workaround is I defined my own carousel control arrow class instead of the pre-defined one from the bootstrap, using script directive from AngularJS:

```
<script ... type="text/ng-template">

<div class='carousel' ng-mouseenter="pause()" ng-mouseleave="play()" ng-swipe-right="prev()" ng-swipe-left="next()">
    <div class="carousel-inner" ng-transclude></div>
    <a class="left-control" ng-click="prev()"> ...</a> //dont use the one from bootstrap which is carousel-control left
</div> 
</script>
```

My CSS:

```
    .carousel {margin-left: 45px; margin-right: 25px;}

    .left-control, .right-control {
         background: none;
        border: none;
   }
.left-control {margin-left: -45px; color: black;}
.right-control {margin-right: -45px; color: black;}
```

I tried to align them nicely into 1 line in my CSS(the left arrow, carousel inner and the right arrow) but I still can't get all of the 3 elements to align properly. Any help is appreciated thanks!

Comment: Probably going to need to see this in action to help you out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might try this code:

```
.left-control,.right-control { position:absolute; }
.left-control {margin-left: -45px; color: black;}
.right-control {margin-right: -45px; color: black;}
```

It makes the elements absolute, so they can be positioned rather freely. You might want to adjust some more with `right:-10px` for `.right-control`. 10px depends on the size of the element. The same goes for the left control button..